# U 20.04 At Boot Error Invalid ELF header magic != JELF

Tags: boot, 20.04

Firstly may I say that I'm not a techie so please keep any answers simple for me.
Running 20.04 on a desktop as a simple installation, no other drives or operating systems.  I've been running 20.04 since it was released and everything has been fine but suddenly I am getting   Invalid ELF header magic != JELF  at Boot stage and the pc just stays at that.
I have managed to reboot and select Ubuntu 20.04 Generic which seems to bypass the problem temporarily.
I was not doing anything to effect the installation, just normal web and Libra Office work before this started.
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Often a grub version issue. Did you at one time have grub in BIOS mode, then re-installed in UEFI mode? Or vice-versa? And system UEFI update reset to defaults? And then wrong version of grub is default boot? Best to see details. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: My apologies, I provided the wrong version number it should have been version 22.04.2 LTS.